# How to uninstall metro device meta data for more option

Tags: c++, visual-c++, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have got device meta data for my camera app from my team.I installed the device metadata using meta data authoring tool.I have following query.since this device keeps changing as team is working on it,i do update the device metadata everyday.

my question is

1. does updating device meta data created new entry in the cache or it updates the existing one.
2. how to uninstall device meta data using tool. presently i am doing it manually by deleting the meta data cache.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess the problem is due to multiple copies of metadata of a device App for device(camera).
I checked all the metadata in

```
%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceMetadataStore
```

using Metadata Authoring tools and compared the package name and deleted it if they were same.    I deleted all related entry from

```
%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceMetadataCache\dmrccache\multiloc
```

one can also compare package Name in SoftwareInfo.xml.
I re installed the metadata.now it is working fine.

Please confirm my finding whether multiple copies of metadata for same device/device app cause problem.